# Persist data in URL

Tags: grails, url-mapping

In grails you have neat configuration of your URLs in the `URLMapping.groovy`. Some parameters however needs to be persisted somehow across multiple calls. E.g. `language`:

- www.example.com/**de**/login
- www.example.com/**de**/myBookings

Therefore we can define mappings like this:

```
"/$language/login" { ... }
"/$language/myBookings" { ... }
```

However then I would need to add language as parameter to all links. I want to have a mechanism which checks some or any url parameters and automatically inserts them the link generator.

Is it therefore somehow possible to override the mapping factory to generate new links based on the current URL?